# Simple Branching Process Simulation in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to make a simple simulation of a branching process. I have 2 types of cell, SC and CM.

SC -> SC + SC, with probability p1

SC -> SC + CM, with probability p2

SC -> CM + CM, with probability p3

SC -> die, with probability p4

CM -> CM + CM, with probability p5

CM -> die. with probability p6

so far, I've managed to create 2 types of breed and set up the initial probability with the setup button command.

```
breed [SCs SC]
breed [CMs CM]       

SCs-own [p1 p2 p3 p4]

CMs-own [p5 p6]

to setup
  clear-all               
  set-default-shape SCs "circle" 
  set-default-shape CMs  "circle"    
  create-SCs 50
  create-CMs 50

  ask SCs [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
    set p1 0.15 ;; 2 SC
    set p2 0.15 ;; SC + CM
    set p3 0.4 ;; CM + CM
    set p4 0.15 ;; die
    set size 1
     ]

  ask CMs [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set p5 0.3 ;; CM + CM
    set p6 0.7 ;; die
    set size 1
     ]  

  reset-ticks
end
```

and then create the go command button, with move-all and reproduce procedure

```
to go
  move-all
  reproduce
  tick
end
```

and this is the move-all procedure

```
to move-all
  ask turtles [
    right random 90
    left random 30
    forward 1
  ]
end
```

now, the problem is with the reproduce command. I want to ask CM to hatch but based on the property of SC (as in p2 and p3). I have a run-time error with the marked command. This is the code

```
to reproduce
  ask SCs [
    if random-float 1 < p1 [
      hatch 1 
    ]

    if random-float 1 < p4 [
      die 
    ]

  ]

    ask CMs [
      if random-float 1 < p5 [
        hatch 1 
      ]

      if random-float 1 < p6 [
        die
      ]

      ;runtime error with this block 
      ;p2 and p3 belong to SC, but I want to hatch 1 CM and 2 CM

      ;if random-float 1 < p2 [ 
      ;  hatch 1
      ;]

      ;if random-float 1 < p3 [
      ;  hatch 2
      ;]

    ]

end
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ? How can I simulate the process with p2 and p3 ? I'm sure most of the experienced Netlogo user would know how to handle this.Thanks...

Comment: "p2 and p3 belong to SC, but I want to hatch 1 CM and 2 CM" — which SC's p2 and p3 do you want to use?

Comment: I've solved this problem by using global variable instead...

Comment: Great. Please either answer your own question so there's a record of the solution — or just delete the question so it won't show up in future searches.